# uloz.to - how to view links of searching results hidden in images (bypass)

Tags: javascript, show, hidden

on the file sharing site http://uloz.to are Searchnig Results (try type something above on that page and click "Vyhledat") hidden by javascript - you cannot copy link adress of any individual searching result, you cannot right click and open result in the tab (window). Everything is hidden to image file. You must click on the specific chosen searching result and after that correct link to file is after that viewed. You copy this and go back and click on another searching result .. and again and again. That behavior is intentional to restrict users from copy links on more searching results once. Is it some solution to bypass this protection for chrome (boomakrlet ..) ?

Comment: need an example or more clarified language to understand.

Comment: the request is clear, for example http://uloz.to/hledej?q=apple give you page with results, but it is not possible copy link of any file or open it in new tab (protection via image, you must go straight troughout image link to another page to givelink adress to file